# Can't pass pandas Series to pyplot's fill_between function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Passing a pandas Series to pyplot's fill_between() function produces the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'> -1
```

However, other pyplot functions seem to be fine with taking Series as inputs (plot() and scatter() seem to work fine with it). I know this issue can be fixed by passing my_series.value instead of my_series, but can someone explain why some pyplot plotting functions seem to be ok with getting a Series as input, while others are not? Which functions will crash when given a Series? Thanks.

Comment: in my case, i get the following error:
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting 
rule ''safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `matplotlib` is written to take sequence or `np.ndarray`-like objects as arguments (and knows nothing about `pandas`).  In the cases where all of the methods used internally work the same on `pandas` objects and `numpy` objects, then it works (the magic of duck typing).  In cases where `pandas` objects do not behave correctly (in this case using `v[-1]` to get the last element of the first dimension out) it will raise errors.

If a given function works with the `pandas` objects depends on the internals of the function and is not guaranteed to be stable even between minor releases of `mpl` because you are essentially using `matplotlib` in an undocumented way.

Answer (score 2):

Till `pandas` is not officially implemented in `plt.fill_between` function, you can still apply `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` as `pd.Series().values` and `pd.DataFrame().values` to make `fill_between` plots.