# Unable to pass a pandas Series to matplotlib fill_between

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the matplotlib [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) command.

The upper and lower bounds, y1, and y2, are "*An N-length array (or scalar) of the y data*"

So in my code I pass y1 and y2 two pandas Series of the appropriate length.  But the code fails with an error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

If I pass simple list of scalars instead, then the chart renders properly.

I thought a data Series would pass as an array for these purposes. But apparently it doesn't.  I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171079/using-fill-between-with-a-pandas-data-series), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910173/cant-pass-pandas-series-to-pyplots-fill-between-function) StackOverflow questions with the same issue.  In both cases, the answer was to pass the .values attribute instead.

It doesn't work for me, though. Despite passing numpy.ndarrays for yUpper, yLower, I still get the same error as if I was passing pandas.Series.  !?

Here is the code fragment, and below that is the print output to prove that I'm passing what I think I'm passing...

```
    high = OI_avg * 1.05
    low = OI_avg * 0.96
    print ("\nOI_avg {1} \n{0}".format(OI_avg, type(OI_avg)))
    print ("\nhigh {1} \n{0}".format(high, type(high)))
    print ("\nlow {1}\n{0}".format(low, type(low)))

    print ("high.values is type {0}".format(type(high.values)))
    print ("low.values is type {0}".format(type(low.values)))

    highHack = [-19914, 1951, 8650, 7031]
    lowHack = [-18207, 1784, 7909, 6428]

    # [CASE 1] passing a simple list of numbers works
    #fill_zone = plt.fill_between(index, highHack, lowHack, label = '+/-1 std dev range', facecolor='lightgray', alpha=0.3)

    # [CASE 2] passing two numpy.ndarray gives the ufunc error!?
    #fill_zone = plt.fill_between(index, high.values, low.values, label = '+/-1 std dev range', facecolor='lightgray', alpha=0.3)    

    # [CASE 3] passing two pandas.Series gives the ufunc error    
    #fill_zone = plt.fill_between(index, high, low, label = '+/-1 std dev range', facecolor='lightgray', alpha=0.3)
```

Below shows that .values is returning a np.ndarray.

```
OI_avg <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
co1 comdty   -18966.1
co2 comdty     1858.7
co3 comdty     8238.9
co4 comdty     6696.5
Name: (d_OI, avg), dtype: object

high <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
co1 comdty    -19914.4
co2 comdty    1951.635
co3 comdty    8650.845
co4 comdty    7031.325
Name: (d_OI, avg), dtype: object

low <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
co1 comdty   -18207.46
co2 comdty    1784.352
co3 comdty    7909.344
co4 comdty     6428.64
Name: (d_OI, avg), dtype: object
high.values is type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
low.values is type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**....So as I wrote this question, I realized that high.values gives me an ndarray of 'dtype = object'.  I thought maybe matplotlib was gagging on the dtype, so I changed the dtype of array to a float.**

```
highArray = high.values.astype(float)
lowArray = low.values.astype(float)
```

And that fixed it, now the code works.   Makes me wonder if I changed the dtype of the original pd.Series to a float, would that have worked.... And the answer is yes.  I can pass a Series.astype(float) directly to matplotlib and it works fine.  No need to intermediate through an ndarray....

Comment: Maybe you should formulate your answer as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Passing the Series' values casted as a float solved the problem

```
highArray = high.values.astype(float)
```